# Sparse matrix time computation

Tags: performance, sparse-matrix

If i store a dense matrix as a coordinate wise sparse matrix instead of n x n 2 dimensional array, what would be the time efficiency? obviously it would be bad if i do store it as a sparse matrix.

Answer (score 0):

You should think what operation you are interested in since the efficiency of various operations differs for each storage format. See for example the various formats (and typical use cases) in [Scipy Sparse](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/sparse.html).

Typically a 'sparse matrix' is defined as a matrix where you can obtain some performance benefits by taking advantage of the fact that many elements are zero. So there should be an advantage to storing a sparse matrix in a sparse format.

The coordinate format (COO) has a space requirement of `3 * nnzs`. So as long as `3 * nnzs < N^2` (your matrix order) you save storage space. Other formats (such as CSR) are more efficient in terms of space (`2 * nnzs + N`) and also support common operations (such as sparse matrix vector multiplication) efficiently.